# standard java library to validate and convert infix to prefix/postfix notation?

Tags: java, parsing, infix-notation, postfix-notation, polish

Is there any java utility to validate and/or convert infix to prefix/postfix

Comment: btw, using ANTLR or JavaCC seems too much for this, isn't it?

Comment: I think they have, it's just not shaped to fit the utensil that you had in mind.  Think "binary tree".

Comment: If a non-trivial proportion of Java programmers regularly found themselves needing to do this, then perhaps thing would be different.  But they don't, so it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library just for this may be seen as an overkill. Or, as [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) points out, it's not a common need.

Comment: It's just not really a common need.

Comment: Sigh, looking for one!